# JSON: How to assign a value to a variable that isn't selected out of a list?

Tags: java, json

this is my first time using stackoverflow so forgive me for showing how new I am. I'm using a program where you label things on an image using a list of possible points of interest (i.e. label a car wheel if it's in an image). However, since I am using this as training data for a predictive software, I need to assign a negative value to the points of interest in the list that I do not label in the image (i.e. since a car wheel is on the list, and the image does not contain a car wheel, I need it to assign a negative value to the car wheel in the JSON file). I have never used JSON before so I don't even know where to start. Here's an example of a section of my code.

```
{
  "name": "Red Line",
  "color": "red",
  "tool": "point"
},
```

How do I assign that a value if it is not chosen? Thank you for any help you guys can provide me.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you can do `"value": null` to indicate that variable does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that I need to somehow assign the value to be negative if I do not choose it. Like I want all the variables to be available, but if I don’t choose it to label the image, then I want it to have a value of -1. I believe just putting null would not allow me to choose the variable.